# React, use it to diff an object

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React framework and am starting to use it. I read that it has an excellent diff algorithm. I was wondering can I use it on an object of mine? And run it a second time and get a resulting object with what was added/removed/changed with oldValue and newValue?

Thanks team

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React itself doesn't expose its diffing algorithm because it is tightly integrated with the virtual DOM implementation.

However, there are standalone NPM modules which will do exactly what you asked for. Check out [flitbit/diff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff), for example.

```
var diff = require('deep-diff');

var lhs = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var rhs = { a: 1, b: 4, d: 5 };

var changes = diff(lhs, rhs);

// changes are
[
  { kind: 'E', path: [ 'b' ], lhs: 2, rhs: 4 },
  { kind: 'D', path: [ 'c' ] },
  { kind: 'N', path: [ 'd' ], rhs: 5 }
]
```

Comment: Aw darn I was hoping React had it all. Thanks for your excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do shallow comparison like this:

You have to use react-with-addons.js.

And then use the `React.addons.shallowCompare` function.

The first argument must be an object with two keys, `props` and `state`. Then the second arg is an object to compare with `props` key in first arg. And third arg is to an object to compare with `state` key in first arg. So if you want to use this outside of a React scope just ignore the third arg and do this:

```
var isDifferent = React.addons.shallowCompare({props:{a:1}}, {a:2});
```

This will return `true` as `a` is `1` in left and `2` in right.

```
var isDifferent = React.addons.shallowCompare({props:{a:1}}, {a:1});
```

This will return `false` as they are both the same.